# Convert Text to Readable Time Value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, time

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to convert this time data to a readable time data to be able to run calculations on it. Having trouble converting it so that excel detects its a time value.

Currently the column is set as "general". I tried changing to time but doesn't work. Even manually adding the Semi-colon doesn't work as well. Not sure why.

Objective: Convert Column [C] "Time Begin Clean" to a readable time-data value to run calculations.

[image]

Comment: `CDate` or `CVDate` will convert something like `10AM` to a time value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the job

```
Sub timeDecimals()
    Dim times, startCell As Range
    Set startCell = ActiveSheet.Range("C2")
    times = startCell.Resize(startCell.End(xlDown).Row - startCell.Row + 1).Value2
    
    Dim current As String, lenCurrent As Integer, i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(times, 1)
        current = times(i, 1)
        lenCurrent = Len(current)
        If lenCurrent = 5 Then
            current = Left(current, 1) & ":" & Right(current, 4)
        ElseIf lenCurrent = 6 Then
            current = Left(current, 2) & ":" & Right(current, 4)
        End If
        times(i, 1) = CVDate(current)
    Next i
    
    With startCell.Resize(UBound(times, 1))
        .Value2 = times
        .NumberFormat = "h:mm am/pm"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error, "Run-Time error '13': Type Mismatch

Comment: @Koolakuf_DR the code works flawlessly on the data in your sample column C (and I even tested it on times like `130AM` and `945PM`). There's nothing I can do if you post sample data which are not _properly_ representative of your _actual_ data...